# SQL Server rand() aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, geo

**Problem:** a table of coordinate lat/lngs. Two rows can potentially have the same coordinate. We want a query that returns a set of rows with unique coordinates (within the returned set). Note that `distinct` is not usable because I need to return the id column which is, by definition, distinct. This sort of works (`@maxcount` is the number of rows we need, `intid` is a unique int id column):

```
select top (@maxcount) max(intid)
from Documents d
group by d.geoLng, d.geoLat
```

It will always return the same row for a given coordinate unfortunately, which is bit of a shame for my use. If only we had a `rand()` aggregate we could use instead of `max()`... Note that you can't use `max()` with guids created by `newid()`.

Any ideas?
(there's some more background here, if you're interested: http://www.itu.dk/~friism/blog/?p=121)

UPDATE: Full solution [here](http://www.itu.dk/~friism/blog/?p=213)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use a CTE for this with the ROW_NUMBER function across lat and long and then use rand() against that. Something like:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
        intID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (
                PARTITION BY geoLat, geoLng
                ORDER BY NEWID()
            ) AS row_num,
        COUNT(intID) OVER (PARTITION BY geoLat, geoLng) AS TotalCount
    FROM
        dbo.Documents
)
SELECT TOP (@maxcount)
    intID, RAND(intID)
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    row_num = 1 + FLOOR(RAND() * TotalCount)
```

This will always return the first sets of lat and lngs and I haven't been able to make the order random. Maybe someone can continue on with this approach. It will give you a random row within the matching lat and lng combinations though.

If I have more time later I'll try to get around that last obstacle.

Comment: This actually works if one replaces the `order by intid` with `newid()`. `partition` seems to impose some of order (which makes good sense) so one has to reshuffle the results in the outer query. Without that reshuffle, all the rows chosen where to the extreme south :-).

Comment: I made the change as you suggested. I have to admit, I'm still learning with CTEs, so this was a good excuse to play around with them. :)  I would have thought that ordering by NEWID() there would only change the ordering within a lat/lng pair.

Answer (score 1):

this doesn't work for you?

```
select top (@maxcount) *
from 
(
    select max(intid) as id from Documents d group by d.geoLng, d.geoLat
) t 
order by newid()
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is that it will always return the same document for a given coordinate, namely the one with the largest id. I'd like that to be random too.

Comment: so just do select top 1 * from ... order by newid()

Comment: I can't `select *` when doing `group by`, can you elaborate?

Comment: i don't see how this solution doesn't work. It's one i've used numerous times.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the idea that DISTINCT only works on one column?  Anyway, you could also use a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I second this, distinct works on ALL columns!  ALl columnst must be unique.

Comment: Your absolutely right, I've refrased the question. The problem remains however.